# Height of outer div not expanding with inner div

Tags: html, css

I have a bodyMain div of 100% width. Inside it is a body div 800px with auto margin(can I use 'body' as id ?). Inside this are two divs bodyLeft and bodyRight 200px and 600px wide respectively. When I add content to inner divs neither bodyMain nor body expands in height . All heights are auto.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/TqxHq/18/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="bodyMain">
      <div id="body">
        <div id="bodyLeft"> left text goes here<br />
        </div>
        <div id="bodyRight">Right text goes here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#bodyMain{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;

}
#body{
    border:1px solid green;
    width:804px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
}
#bodyLeft{
     border:1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    width:200PX;
    height:auto;
}
#bodyRight{
    border:1px solid orange;
    float:right;
    width:600PX;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You must add

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

at the end of floating div to fix this issue. see 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/TqxHq/20/)

Problem happens when a floated element is within a container box and element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow. You can use 2 methods to fix it:

```
clear:both
clearfix
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was facing the same problem and fixed by adding this block of code.

Answer (score 8):

This is a common issue when working with floats. There are a couple of common solutions:

1. Add a div after the floats with clear: both
2. Add the two floats into a container with the CSS attribute `overflow: auto`
3. Make the parent element a float
4. Using the :after CSS pseudo element with the CSS: `.clearfix:after {content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden;}`
5. Adding a set height to the parent element

[See this article](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is to have outer div overflow:hidden (in style attribute).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion with predefined tag names, refrain from using `body`, `html`, or `head` as ID attribute values.

I agree with Muhammed Irfan's idea. I don't agree with his method though. Avoid inline styling except for small snippets. Especially in this case, because it is likely that there will be another case where `clear: both` is necessary. So, add a div, give it a meaningful class name and apply the additional CSS.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqxHq/24/) for an example.

Comment: I agree, just i focused on main issue rather than inline styling. you should or must create class to call whenever needed.

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dt5NR/)*

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#bodyMain{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; /*added*/
    border:1px solid red;
    /*removed height:auto;*/
    /*removed width:100%;*/
}
#body{
    display:table;/*added*/
    border:1px solid green;
    width:804px;
    margin: 0 auto; /*improved*/
}
#bodyLeft{
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    /*removed height:auto;*/
}
#bodyRight{
    border:1px solid orange;
    float:right;
    width:600px;
    /*removed height:auto;*/
}
```

Comment: Please explain the changes. I'm new to designing.

Comment: Sure, look: `DIV` is by default a `block` level element, so it's width is set by default to 100%. Same for `height:auto;`. So we don't need it. Setting `display:table;` we ensure the element to act like a `table` element, and it always fits the height to contain its 'cells'. If you want you can make a search about: *adding overflow hidden to DIV parent elements*. +1 to your interesting question.